# Google Maps Добавить форму отправки

Tags: google-maps-api, карты, map

Ребята помогите пожалуйста, как сделать вот такую кастомную карту, хочу добавить к Google map background и сделать форму отправки[image: введите сюда описание изображения] на карте ?

Comment: создаете блок родитель с `position:relative' внутрь вставляете блок с картой и следом блок с формой, только блоку с формой задаете `position:absolute` и выравниваете по середине

Comment: Я добавил карту через API вот код который  прописал в блоке и он не работает    <section id="map">
  <form action="" >
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
  </form>
 </section>